# Is there a source for the claim that a person's day has more blessing if they wake up early?

Tags: sources-mekorot, sleep

I remember someone saying in a shiur a long time ago that a person's day is blessed if they wake up early. Is there any source for this claim?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'day is blessed'? All the way in the first Siman of Shulchan Aruch (and commentaries), it extolls the virtues of waking up early, is that what you're looking for? https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.1?lang=bi

Comment: @Salmononius2 If I recall correctly, this person meant to say that a person who wakes up early is usually more successful in his life.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.9b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Answer (score 8):

The Gemara in [Brachos 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.9b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) mentions that if one davens in the morning at sunrise,
" k'vasikin", he will not be harmed all day. Sounds like a good blessing to me :)

I once saw this quoted :  "  HaRav Kanievsky points out that if a Tanna would appear in our days--one who we knew whose brachos were fulfilled--oh, how we would try to receive his bracha.  When Chazal themselves give us the bracha of davening Vasikin--how we should strive to receive it!"

The Mishna Berura in 98:8 quotes this as well.

The Shulchan Aruch says that one who does so " receives great reward".

Comment: Great answer. Do you happen to know where/when HaRav Kanievsky said this? Seems like an interesting source.

Comment: @Zachary Green Actually the Gemara says something different. It says that one who juxtaposes redemption and prayer at sunrise will incur no harm for the entire day. It also says that the vasikin would conclude the recitation of Shema with sunrise in order to juxtapose the blessing of redemption, which immediately follows the recitation of Shema, with prayer, and pray during the day.